# Adding multiple numbers to existing data

Tags: microsoft-excel

What if I wanted to add multiple numbers in different cells at the same time for example:

Each number represents a cell

```
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```

I would then like to add the below in one easy swoop by pasting the numbers on top of the existing.

```
0   5   5   5   4   2   4   2
```

Hope you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand well your question:

- select the range you want to add and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- select the other range, where you want to get the results
- go to "home" - "paste" - "paste special"; select "add" and press "ok"

Comment: Thanks, I realised the problem was I had a formula within the data I was pasting into the existing cells, I've basically followed what you said above but added paste special "value" which has rectified the problem! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the block of cells and then *PasteSpecial* with the *Add* option on top of the destination cells.